# Tool to analyze and track resource usage on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I know there are responses for Windows 7 but I am looking for Windows XP

I am what I would consider a power user, at a given time I am likely to have 4-5 terminal instances, Eclipse, Websphere, Word, Notes, etc running fairly heavily on a pretty mediocre machine running **Windows XP**. My appeals to get a better laptop (or use my own) have been hindered by the fact that the help desk cannot find anything "wrong". I thought I might be able to make my case by tracking my resource usage.

At a minimum I am looking for something like top where it shows me avg load over a period, but I would prefer some kind of historical tracking.

Anyone have a good tool?

Comment: Not on windows 7 did you read the title? XPerf is in the Windows 7 SDK.

Comment: No, I didn't read anything here. I didn't read the title, I didn't read the question itself and I also completely ignored the tags. I just posted the link at random. That's what I always do. That's why I'm a moderator here, because I go around posting random, unrelated links in the comments section of questions.

Comment: Then why did you link to a question on Windows 7 I don't get it.

Comment: Also if we are going to continue having this considered a duplicate, perhaps we should include a link to the duplicate question since the previous was deleted.

Comment: If you don't realize why this is possibly a duplicate of said question, then you might have actually missed some of the posted information on the other question. If you've only seen the reference to xperf, then I would advise you to take another look. If the other posted material is not sufficient for your case, then the other question should be extended instead of having a new question for every single permutation to which the existing questions might not apply. Also, a link to the other question has been placed at the top of the body of this question. Have a nice day

Comment: While there are limited answers for XP in the duplicate question, this is still a dupe.  If you're wanting to promote the other question, or would like more detail, consider placing a bounty (or if you're in good graces with others, [they might do it for you](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3905/47225))

Comment: If that is the case then why are tools like pipe, echo, top and others not a valid answer to that question? Wouldn't those be included in an overly general (OS agnostic) view? And if that is in fact the case shouldn't the mentioned question be edited to reflect that? Can you repost the question link? Maybe I missed something but my once over the first time saw nothing that would work on XP. Why did you delete it in the first place? In addition most of the tools that would work on XP (Process monitor) do not TRACK the information, merely they convey it.

Comment: Also why are there separate tags for windows-xp and windows-7 if this is the case? Is this really how the moderators are on this site? So conceited that they believe it is necessary to talk down on someone after they were asking for clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows Performance Monitor should tell you everything you need to know, plus it will log all info over time for you.

1. To access it on Windows **XP**: Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Peformance
2. Add the counters you want to keep track of by clicking the + button on the toolbar. There are all kinds of things you can measure, but some key ones will under the "Memory" performance object, such as Page Faults/sec and Available Bytes.
3. Once you have the set of counters you want, right-click and save them using Save As...
4. Now, to generate a log, go to "Performance Logs and Alerts" on the left side and right click on "New Log Settings From..." and select the file you saved in the previous step.
5. Choose where you want to save the log file and other properties
6. Start the Log counter